# How to create a crypto hot wallet that can be integrated into a website to allow deposit and withdraws

Tags: cryptography

I would like guides and directions of where to start, resources I can use to understand the topic better. The deposit and withdraw system would be very similar to crypto exchanges where the user will have their own addresses to deposit different cryptos and can withdraw them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the BSV library. Albeit for safer non custodial wallets. But this does not mean to say you cannot integrate that with cloud apps.

It's done superbly by Handcash already.

There's excellent support docs and tutorials using live main and test net addresses at Satolearn and BSV Academy.